# So, how exactly does the Java main method work?

Tags: java, command-line, command-line-arguments

`public static void main(String [] args)`

This thing has been quite the enigma ever since I started programming. I understand it passes an array of Strings to the command line, but where exactly does it do that and how does it interpret it?

I'm pretty sure I'm wrong here, but my current understanding is that whatever you write in the main method is then translated into machine and passed into the computer as a string. Well, that's all fine and dandy, but then how does it understand numeric values if everything is a String?

Also, it's a bit weird when it comes to methods. Usually, when designing a method, you would write the formal parameters that you'd pass to it, and what you want to do with those parameters. But with the main method, you are defining the parameters while you're writing the code inside the main method! how does that even work?

Comment: It works just like any other method, only it's called from the operating system.

Comment: "passes an array of Strings to the command line" ... No, it **receives** an array of Strings **from** the command line

Answer (score 4):

The `public static void main(String[] args)` method in Java is the method that gets called when the user starts running your program. Inside this method, it is up to you to write whatever code (classes and methods) you need to make the program work.

Yes, parameters for this method are strings, but this is because when the program is executed from the command line, these args are the parameters that the user typed after the name of the class to execute. It is up to your code to parse them into numbers if that is what you require.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm pretty sure I'm wrong here, but my current understanding is that
>   whatever you write in the main method is then translated into machine
>   and passed into the computer as a string. Well, that's all fine and
>   dandy, but then how does it understand numeric values if everything is
>   a String?

This statement doesn't make particular sense.  Yes, the class, which may contain the `main` method, is compiled to byte code, which can be read/interpreted by the JVM and executed on the machine.

When the JVM is executed (by running the `java` command) it looks for the `main` method in the specified class (or if you are executing a jar file, the class specified by the `Main-Class` manifest entry).  If found, it will pass the command line parameters as a `String` array to your `main` method.

> Also, it's a bit weird when it comes to methods. Usually, when
>   designing a method, you would write the formal parameters that you'd
>   pass to it, and what you want to do with those parameters. But with
>   the main method, you are defining the parameters while you're writing
>   the code inside the main method! how does that even work?

Because it's impossible for the JVM to know what parameters might be sent to it from the command line, it wraps all the parameters up within a `String` array, meaning that, you could have lots and lots of different parameters sent to your `main` method.

It is up to you to interpret these parameters based on the needs of your program and determine if they suitable enough for you to continue execution.

Take a look at:

- [Chapter 12 of the Java Language Specification: Execution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html)
- [Lesson: A Closer Look at the "Hello World!" Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter)

for more details.

Historically, the `main` method comes from C/C++ as they also have a concept of a `main` function which operates in a similar fashion

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the internals of the JVM, but assuming it is running on a typical Linux/Unix systems, here are some possibilities:

1) The JVM itself is the actual program that is invoked giving it the the .class name as the input (containing the main method) along with additional args if needed - e.g.:

java SomeProgram input1 input2 .....

where SomeProgram.class is the compiled from SomeProgram.java which is the class that has the usual main() method.

2) Now the JVM in a typical Linux/Unix environment is a 'ELF binary' (executable and linking format) which has the 'main' method defined. All the gory details are described here including how the inputs are passed from a shell to a running executable (on a Intel platform):

http://linuxgazette.net/84/hawk.html

3) In short the JVM gets the inputs as described in (2), and then effectively runs the Someclass.main() method by copying all the inputs to the String[] array.

4) All inputs are treated as String, so if you need to treat some inputs as numeric, you would need to explicitly cast them as needed.

Although the ELF standard is part of Linux/Unix systems, I am assuming something similar is happening in other platforms supporting Java.

I am hoping someone with more understanding of JVM internals can correct me if I am wrong.